# How to unit test this class?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0

I am new to Visual Studio Unit testing framework and Unit testing.

```
class Request
{       
   private Dictionary<string, List<int>> processedText = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
   Public bool Method1(string input)
   {
      //intialize processedText to some values based on input.

   } 
   public int Method2()
   {
      //use the processedText.
   }
}
```

Now I am not sure how to unit test this code?

My question is it a good programming practice to have a global variable, initialize it and use in other methods?

Is my code unit testable? Any links which helps in honing my Unit testing skills would be of great use. I went through few tutorials but never came across such a situation.

Comment: Just a note, that's an instance variable, not a global variable (and yes you can initialise it in one method and use it in another).

Answer (score 0):

- Having a class level private variable does not deter you from doing
  unit testing. But having a  static variable will.
- I don't see any
  return values or output parameters from the methods. So what will you
  be validating the results with?
- Otherwise making sure that the code
  is independent and uses proper mock objects in case of dependent
  objects, then it should be alrite.

Comment: one method returns bool and the other int.

Comment: ok. contrary to your perception automated unit testing is very simple. Infact you can write some class and implement the framework on your own. But VSTS and nUnit etc., have simplified this process for you. It is another piece of code which supplies the parameters and checks the results. You need to make sure you include all your test cases as unit tests here. Take a look at this link which I got through google which explains about nUnit to get an understanding http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5171/Advanced-Unit-Testing-Part-IV-Fixture-Setup-Teardo.

Answer (score 0):

To make a class testable you have to set up three fundamental sections:

- Arrange: this is where you set up the test cases, that is, input values that will be passed to your method, any class initialization code (maybe by mocking an dependency, etc.)
- Act: this is where you execute the unit test with the arrangement of values you have set up and where you **get** a result.
- Assert: this is the step where you verify the results. In other words, did your code pass the test?

The code you posted is *not* unit testable because there's no way to verify the results. If the results you need to verify are dependent on a different source, like a database or file, then you're writing an *integration test*.

Here's an example of a unit test and code that can be unit tested. Forgive the lame example:

```
[TestClass]
public class CalculatorTest 
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_Two_Numbers_Are_Passed_To_The_Add_Method_The_Result_Should_Be_The_Addition_Of_The_Two_Numbers() 
    {
        // Arrange
        double x = 1.0;
        double y = 2.0;
        double expectedResult = 3.0;
        ICalculator calculator = new Calculator();

        // Act
        double actualResult = calculator.Add(x, y);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
}
```

Here's the class that will pass the test:

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public double Add(double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public interface ICalculator
{
    double Add(x, y);
}
```

Now, by "unit testing" are you referring to TDD?

Comment: Looks like you edited your question before I posted my answer. Both methods in the original code you posted returned `void`, which is why I concluded that your code was not unit-testable, unless you were writing an integration test. I hope the example I provided still helps.